# Authorize.Net unable to update expiration date

Tags: authorize.net

I am trying to update the expiration date of an existing profile un Authorize.Net. I am able to retrieve the profile information, but when I call the api with `updateCustomerPaymentProfileRequest` xml I get:

> E00003 The 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd:number' element is invalid - The value XX is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The actual length is less than the MinLength value.

This is the xml:

```
<updateCustomerPaymentProfileRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
    <merchantAuthentication xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
        <name xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">bob123</name>
        <transactionKey xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">somesecretehere</transactionKey>
    </merchantAuthentication>
    <refId xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">id1</refId>
    <customerProfileId xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">12345</customerProfileId>
    <paymentProfile xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
        <billTo xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
            <firstName xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">Bilbo</firstName>
            <lastName xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">Baggins</lastName>
            <address xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">100 Main St.</address>
            <city xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">Some City</city>
            <state xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">ME</state>
            <zip xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">12345</zip>
        </billTo>
        <payment xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
            <creditCard xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
                <cardNumber xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">XXXX1111</cardNumber>
                <expirationDate xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">2049-04</expirationDate>
            </creditCard>
        </payment>
    </paymentProfile>
    <validationMode xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">liveMode</validationMode>
</updateCustomerPaymentProfileRequest>
```

Comment: Is that error message really saying `XX`? If not, what value is actually there?

Comment: Yes, that is the exact error message.

Comment: It looks like the credit card number must be provided and cannot be truncated

Comment: That is what appears to be happening, but this is from their docs: "Note: If some fields in this request are not submitted or are submitted with a blank value, the values in the original profile are removed. As a best practice to prevent this from happening, call getCustomerPaymentProfileRequest to receive all current information including masked payment information. Change the field or fields that you wish to update, and then reuse all the fields you received, with updates, in a call to updateCustomerPaymentProfileRequest."

Comment: Have you tried omitting the card number field?

Comment: I don't see a customerPaymentProfileId being submitted with your request, to update a customer payment profile, you need to include a customer payment profile id (_<customerPaymentProfileId>123456</customerPaymentProfileId>_)

Comment: That was a bit of a hack of the actual xml being sent, since we don't want to actually log it, so customerPaymentProfileId was missing. What was also different was an empty driversLicense element that got included in the actual XML. This was causing the AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd:number error. I removed that element and the updates worked as expected IF you include the masked CC number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual XML sent was more like this:

```
<updateCustomerPaymentProfileRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
    <merchantAuthentication xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
        <name xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">bob123</name>
        <transactionKey xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">somesecretehere</transactionKey>
    </merchantAuthentication>
    <refId xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">id1</refId>
    <customerProfileId xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">12345</customerProfileId>
    <paymentProfile xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
        <billTo xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
            <firstName xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">Bilbo</firstName>
            <lastName xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">Baggins</lastName>
            <address xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">100 Main St.</address>
            <city xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">The Shire</city>
            <state xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">ME</state>
            <zip xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">12345</zip>
        </billTo>
        <payment xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
            <creditCard xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
                <cardNumber xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">XXXX1111</cardNumber>
                <expirationDate xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">2049-04</expirationDate>
            </creditCard>
        </payment>
        <driversLicense xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
            <number xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd"></number>
            <state xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd"></state> 
            <dateOfBirth xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd"></dateOfBirth>
        </driversLicense>
        <customerPaymentProfileId xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">999</customerPaymentProfileId>
    </paymentProfile>
    <validationMode xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">liveMode</validationMode>
</updateCustomerPaymentProfileRequest>
```

Note the Empty **driversLicense** element. The number element was the actual culprit. Once I removed the entire driversLicense element from the XML all worked as expected. It pays to double check the actual XML.